# Android studio Error during Sync: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android, connection, adb

I've been debugging for months with a physical Samsung pad connected via USB and now I can't load the app on the device for debugging.  I rebooted everything yesterday and it worked until this afternoon!  I get the same error all the time.  The ADB appears to be running on port 5037.

I'm disappointed in how buggy the development environment is and feel like I'm spinning my wheels like back in the Win3 days fighting the environment instead of the app.  Any suggestions would be appreciated...

```
3:11 PM Gradle build finished in 2s 40ms
3:11 PM Error during Sync: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
3:11 PM Session 'app': Error Installing APK
```

I'm using USB debugging.  I've tried everything I can find on SO and nothing works:

```
1) Rebooted both laptop and device many times
2) Deleted app from device
3) Manually updated the SDK to 8.1.0 (auto update fails with file size error)
4) Unplugged and tried a different USB port
5) Updated the Samsung Android ADB interface from Win7 device manager
6) Killed adb via task manager and SDK kill-server and start-server
7) Turned USB / Developer mode off and on again
8) Deleted the device from Win Device Manager; re-scanned; updated driver software
```

Comment: Well, I don't know why this worked but I changed the USB cable and plugged into another port (one which I tried before) and now it works. I went back to the original cable and port and it works! One thing I noticed was when it didn't work there was a funky named (almost like a GUID) virtual device listed in the Select Deployment Target dialog; the Samsung pad did't show. When I unplugged and re-plugged the USB cable in the pad showed up and the weird device went away but the ADB still wouldn't launch. So net net, orig cable and port; no funky virtual device; works; don't know why.

Comment: I had selected that as an answer and the debugger has been working all day.  All of a sudden it broke again and the same wack-o virtual device showed up and the Samsung pad is not showing.

Here's a screen shot:  https://imgur.com/a/R3TA6

Comment: Update - When I unplug the Samsung pad the temp device goes away.  Plug back in the Samsung pad showed up and the debugger worked!

Comment: Update 2 - Same thing again.  This time new port and no luck.  So I unplugged; rebooted the pad and laptop (of course Win7 decided it was time to do a 30 min update); plugged in and it works....at least for now

Comment: Update 3 - I'm not 100% sure but it seems like this error happens when the Samsung pad is in sleep mode and I try to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make this happen at will now and it seems like it happens when the device goes into sleep mode.  So I'm debugging and all is working well and the  problem occurs.  I stop the app via Android Studio and reboot the Samsung pad.  After that I get the funky temp device showing up and the ADB won't install.  The fix is to unplug the USB cable.  Wait about 1 minuet and plug back in.  The temp device is gone and the pad shows up.  All works well.

Comment: Update -- This happened all over again but this time I couldn't make the above work even after a factory reset of the device.  Net net it turns out the USB cable was bad and replacing resolved all the issues.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error.
There is low RAM in the system. I just closed some programs (Chrome used 1GB) and restart Android Studio.
Try also delete folder "build" and "app/build".